# BlackBerry BBM Api

Tags: blackberry, java-me, jde

Is is possible to "PING!!!" a BBM contact using the "net.rim.blackberry.api.blackberrymessenger.Message" API? If yes, how would I do so? If not, how should I go about doing this?

Thank you all for your help! Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The BBM API which allows people to Ping is not available to the Public.
If you were a RIM employee and had access to the internal APIs then you could do this, but the public API does not allow you to do this.